# Creating Bootstrap panel and styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys been playing around with the bootstrap pannels and trying to understand it all. I am trying to recreate some panels inside other panels.

So for example this website : [Website](https://juicerecipes.com/recipes/)

Is using bootstrap pannels for their recopies. This is what i am trying to recreate with panels however i am not sure how 2 do this. 
I have done this so far however it does not look like the one on the website at all

Code:

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container">
  <div class = "pannels">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Title</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
            <h4>
            List Title
            </h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">Item One</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Item One</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Item One</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
      Here comes some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get everything to the right size. So for example my picture tab is not the right size compared to the site and i am having problem recreating it. I also am struggling to shrink the whole window pannel . I am not sure if i should use CSS to do this or bootstrap etc.

Anyway any help on this would be great .

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have highly specific styles like what you're looking for. You will have to use CSS, perhaps overriding default Bootstrap styles to get your desired results.

Comment: Ah ok , but to get the layout , that would all be done in bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap is a library for highly common layouts & functionality, so it is a great choice for getting started. You can make personalized tweaks to the layout it gives by redefining various classes with your desired widths, heights, margins, padding, colors, etc. by linking your own CSS file **after** the Bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: Ah thats great,, hopefully someone will check my code above and see if its right

Comment: Make sure the wrap groups of panels (such as in your first column) with a `panel-group` div, & add the `panel-group` class to the panel that contains other panels (to remove space at the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS. So in your head tag add a link to your own CSS file which adds the styles you want. But make sure it is listed **after** you link the Bootstrap CSS file.

Ex.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="--Bootstrap URL Here--"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCustomCSSFile.css"/>
```

Then inside `myCustomCSSFile.css` put things like:

```
panel > panel {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

or whatever styles you want.

Here's a CSS tutorial: [W3Schools CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)